# SMT validity solvers/ quantifier elimination in Ocaml

Tags: algorithms, first-order-logic, formal-methods, smt-solvers, logical-validity

I am working on my own expression package in Ocaml and have to perform both validity queries and quantifier elimination. I have already implemented Cooper's procedure (for Presburger and Linear Integer arithmetic), but I assume it is much slower than other implementations.

Because of this, and since Presburger/LIA is not the only arithmetic for which I need validity/quantifier elimination, I thought of packages within this language.

I am looking for a suitable SMT validity checker in Ocaml that

1. not only solves formulae when they are closed (i.e. when they are sentences), but also
2. when the formula is not closed, it returns a theory-equivalent formula without the innermost quantifier(s). That is, I am looking for a quantifier-elimination algorithm.

I am planning to implement a translator from my expressions, to the ones of this tool.

Can anyone provide any information? I also accept other ideas (of which I have little knowledge) such as: using Ocaml as the main language and making use of some sort of calls to other (black-box) languages that perform the asked task.

I am particularly interested in:

- Presburger/integer arithmetic -say, the Omega test or Cooper's procedure.
- Linear Real/Rational arithmetic -say, Fourier-Motzkin or Ferrante-Rackoff's procedure.
- Nonlinear (real) arithmetic / Real closed fields -say, Tarski-Seidenberg's procedure or Cylindrical Algebraic Decomposition.
- Complex arithmetic / Algebraically closed fields -say, Harrison's or Ierardi's procedure.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you acquainted with Kroening & Strichman's [Decision Procedures](https://www.decision-procedures.org)?

Comment: Have you considered writing an OCaml wrapper for, say, [QEPCAD](https://www.usna.edu/CS/qepcadweb/B/QEPCAD.html)?

Comment: Hi! (1) I have that book, but no implementation is offered. (2) I am trying to avoid the implementations. I am trying to find kind of a Z3 with tactics such as Quantifier elimination (like in Python), for Ocaml.

Comment: Yep, that is precisely what I would want: avoiding implementing all the quantifier elimination methods I need! I would like to know how to use these z3 calls (imagine a Z3 from Python as a black box) as black boxes from Ocaml. Can you answer it a little more extended and I can mark the question as answered that way? I mean, for me that is a solution for my question: I would only need to adapt my expression package to suit the input of that black box.

Comment: On Z3, why don't you ask on Stack Overflow? One of the creators of Z3 is active there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z3

Comment: I will, thanks!